# Excel VBA For-Loop only runs in debug mode

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out why the following code only works in debug mode...

When I hit my "Save" button the macro saves every data entry even if it's the same company name. When I debug the macro goes into the for-loop and gives me the message "Company already exists".

Where is my error?

```
Sub Copy_Values()

Dim sapcolleague As String, str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String

Dim i As Integer, ValueToFind As String, ValueToCheck As String
Dim totalAccRows As Integer
Dim accColumn As Integer
Dim currentAccRow As Integer

accColumn = 2
totalAccRows = Worksheets("DB").Cells(Rows.Count, accColumn).End(xlUp).Row
ValueToFind = Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F13").Value

For currentAccRow = 2 To totalAccRows
    If Cells(currentAccRow, accColumn).Value = ValueToFind Then
        MsgBox ("Company already exists!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next


Worksheets("DB").Range("A8").EntireRow.Insert

Worksheets("DB").Range("A8").Value = 
Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F11").Value
Worksheets("DB").Range("B8").Value = 
Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F13").Value
Worksheets("DB").Range("C8").Value = 
Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F15").Value

str1 = Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F18").Value
str2 = Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F19").Value
str3 = Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F20").Value

sapcolleague = str1 & " " & str2 & " " & str3

Worksheets("DB").Range("D8").Value = sapcolleague

' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
MsgBox "Successfully saved!"


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the connection between Save and this macro?

Comment: `If Cells(currentAccRow, accColumn).Value = ValueToFind Then` here Cells will refer to which ever sheet happens to be the active sheet.  It's best to qualify *every* use of Range/Cells with a worksheet object.  When debugging you may have a different sheet selected.  Use `If Worksheets("DB").Cells(currentAccRow, accColumn).Value = ValueToFind Then`

Comment: great hint! I was not making sure to refer to the correct worksheet. Your proposal worked!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `If Cells(currentAccRow, accColumn).Value = ValueToFind Then` the `Cells` has no parent worksheet so it is going to be the ActiveSheet at the time of running.

Quick rewrite:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Values()

    Dim sapcolleague As String, valueToFind As String, accColumn As Long

    With Worksheets("DB")

        accColumn = 2
        valueToFind = Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F13").Value

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(valueToFind, .Columns(accColumn), 0)) Then
                MsgBox ("Company already exists!")
                Exit Sub
        End If


        .Range("A8").EntireRow.Insert

        .Range("A8:C8").Value = Array(Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F11").Value, _
                                      valueToFind, _
                                      Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F15").Value)

        sapcolleague = Join(Array(Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F18").Value, _
                                  Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F19").Value, _
                                  Worksheets("Maintain").Range("F20").Value), Chr(32))

        .Range("D8").Value = sapcolleague
    End With

    'Shouldn't it be saved somewhere around here?

    ' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
    MsgBox "Successfully saved!"

End Sub
```

Comment: The "save" might be referring to copying the information from the "Maintain" sheet and "saving" it into the "DB" sheet.